# Ticket to Ride local multiplayer has stopped working

Tags: steam, technical-issues, ticket-to-ride

I've been playing Ticket to Ride against my siblings each weekend with each of us on a different laptop with a different Steam account. This weekend though we have been having serious problems getting a game going. We seem to run into one of two main problems:

a) A player creates a game and one of the other players can't see the game when they select the join a game option.

b) The local game is visible to the other players but when one of them joins the game a few seconds later they get a message popup saying something like "Unexpected Error" in the title bar and "Disconnected from server" as the message.

I've tried restarting the game, Steam and the laptops to no avail. Turning off the firewall software hasn't helped either.

Comment: this is going to sound pretty repetitive considering it's the age-old question, but have you checked your router etc.? also, is it only Ticket to Ride that's having local multiplayer issues, or all Steam games on your collective accounts? also also, how often do the problems happen, and is there any time where they "fix themselves" for short periods of time?

Comment: I did try rebooting the router. The problem seems to have fixed itself somehow since then.

Comment: good to know! if the problem resurfaces, just make a comment here talking about it :D